# Sort my questions and answers by number of downvotes

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've recently begun actively trying to become a better member of the Stack Overflow community. I've used the site for a few years now and previously as a new user asked some poor questions and probably supplied some poor answers.

I'd like to see which of my questions and answers have the most down votes so I can prioritize which ones I edit/improve. I realize I could go through them individually, especially as I have not really got that many to search through, however I'm sure there are other users out there with many more questions and answers who may want to see similar information.

I'm considering editing this question to request a general "Help me become a better member of this community" section to my account summary that could suggest posts that I could improve, perhaps indirectly suggest what flags have been raised against posts, in such a way that helps me realize what is wrong with them etc. I know that is a bit hand-holdy, but I could have used it two years back, and it would be a lot less <s>brutal</s> blunt than some of the community feedback some new users can get!

Comment: ...but none of your [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/921224/sebastian-troy?tab=questions&sort=votes) or [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/921224/sebastian-troy?tab=answers) have a net negative score.

Comment: @Tanner Exactly, but some *may* still have down votes, I can sort by the total of up votes and down votes, but it may be that some have more down votes than others, that are masked by up votes. I realise that this doesn't particularly apply to me, it was mostly just an idea to help others.

Comment: Simply use the Answers and Questions link in your profile's Activity tab.  Click on "Votes" to sort them by votes.  Click away some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.

Comment: @HansPassant but that just sorts them by the number of up votes and down votes combined...

Comment: Use a SEDE query, like [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66528/my-downvoted-posts).

Comment: @SebastianTroy but if they're net-positive, unless you've had specific feedback in comments, why do you think there's anything you should change?

Comment: @jonrsharpe not every down voter leaves constructive/any feedback. Just running the above SEDE queryhas alerted me that I might need to flag one of my generally up voted questions as a duplicate!

Comment: If flagged as duplicate, you get an auto-comment. My point is that if they *haven't* left feedback, all you have is some downvotes that are outweighed by the upvotes; what's the problem? Why change what most voters actually approved of?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was just going through my old Q&As and trying to improve their quality. Something that I'm sure a lot of users might want to do after a few years experience on the site. If they have many, then a good indicator of quality/need of attention is downvotes. I guess a couple of years ago I didn't care about the auto comment from the flag, but now I do!

Comment: @SebastianTroy I am one such person, but you can only judge it by yourself and not by the votes - especially small numbers of votes are incredibly unreliable as it may not be the quality of your question/answer that is to blame, but rather the quality of the person that voted. I'm sorry, but doing the right thing usually requires personal sacrifice; there are no easy answers ;)